Topological entropy of a Bernoulli Shift
I am approaching the world of entropy and I would like to have a few examples in mind. I know some chaotic systems that are topologically conjugated to the Bernoulli shift, so I would like to know the topological entropy of the latter. I am quite sure the calculation is doable.
I introduce the context for simplicity. Consider the space of infinite words in two symbols $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$, with open sets being a finite intersection of "basic cylinders" $[a]_i$ (here $a=0$ or $1$ and $i \in \mathbb{N}$): the set of words that have $a$ in position $i$. I think this topology is also induced by a distance, that is $d(w_1,w_2) =1/2^c$ where $c$ is the number of characters the two words share consecutively at the beginning.
The Bernoulli shift on $X$ is given by $T(X_0, X_1, \ldots) =(X_1, \ldots)$.
The topological entropy is defined as follows. The topological entropy $H(C)$ of a cover $C$ of $X$ is the logarithm of the minimum number of sets in $C$ needed to cover $X$. The join $\vee$ of two covers is given by the pair wise intersections of one set coming from the fist cover and one set coming from the second. The topological entropy of the Bernoulli shift is the sup over all finite covers $C$ of $X$ of
$$H(T,C) := \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} H(C \vee T^{-1}C \ldots T^{-n}C) $$
EDIT: in case of a compact metric space (as our space is), there is the following alternative formulation. Define the $n$-th iterated metric with respect to $T$ as
$$ d_n(x,y)=\max\{d(T^i(x),T^i(y)): 0\leq i<n\}$$
Points close in this metric stay close during the first $n$ iterations of the shift.  A subset of the space is said to be $(n, \varepsilon)$-separated if each pair of distinct points is at least $\varepsilon$ apart in the metric $d_n$. Denote by $N(n, \varepsilon)$ the maximum cardinality of an $(n, \varepsilon)$-separated set. The topological entropy of $T$ can be computed as
$$ h(f)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \left(\limsup_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\log N(n,\epsilon)\right).$$

The $(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$-Bernoulli measure is a Parry measure that is of maximal entropy, so the metric entropy which is $1$ (directly computable using Sinai generator theorem) attains the topological entropy.
There is a general formula for shifts with irreducible adjacency matrix $A$ (in this case is $A_{ij}\equiv1$) given by $$h_{\text{top}}(T)=\log_2(\lambda_{\textrm{max}})$$
where $\lambda_{\textrm{max}}$ is the Perron-Frobenius eigenvalue of $A$.
